# fragment not refreshing immediately in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I want the likes to be posted on the home page fragment. But now like counts does not add immediately in the profile page fragments,taking some time to load the like count.

This is the code for `PostFragment`.

```
public class PostFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView recyclerView;
    CustomPostAdapter adapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedsList = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
    private String LiveUrl,LiveUrl1, userID;
    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    public static final String TAG = "PostFragment";
    ImageButton btnBack;
    TextView emptyView;
    boolean delete=false;
    String like="like",unlike="unlike";

    //Progresswheel
    ProgressWheel pw;
    ResetPasswordActivity obj=new ResetPasswordActivity();

    public PostFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static Fragment newInstance(String userID) {

        Fragment fragment = new PostFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("userid", userID);
        System.out.println("userid in post instance" + userID);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        LiveUrl = sharedPreferences.getString("liveurl2", null);
        LiveUrl1 = sharedPreferences.getString("liveurl3", null);
        System.out.println("Liveurl1" + LiveUrl);
        userID = sharedPreferences.getString("useridfromprofile", null);
        System.out.println("userid from profile" + userID);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        if (arguments != null) {
            // then you have arguments
            System.out.println("inside argument");
            System.out.println("inside user" + arguments.getString("userid"));
            userID = arguments.getString("userid");
        } else {
            // no arguments supplied...
            System.out.println("outside argument");
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
            userID = sharedPreferences.getString("useridfromprofile", null);
            System.out.println("userid from profile" + userID);
        }

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post, container, false);
        FontChangeCrawler fontChanger = new FontChangeCrawler(getContext().getAssets(), "arial.ttf");
        fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup) v);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        System.out.println("Home");
        /*btnBack = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.button_back);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("delete value inside button click"+delete);
                if(delete)
                {
                    getChildFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(
                                R.id.individualfragment,
                                EditprofileFragment.newInstance(null),
                                EditprofileFragment.TAG)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();

                }
                else {getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();}

            }
        });*/

        pw=(ProgressWheel)v.findViewById(R.id.pw_spinner);
        obj.styleRandom(pw, v.getContext());

        recyclerView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        emptyView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        getProfilePosts();
        adapter = new CustomPostAdapter(getContext(), feedsList, PostFragment.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        feedsList.clear();
        feedsList.addAll(feedsList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                }

                // Handle ListView touch events.
                v.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });


        return v;

    }

    public void getProfilePosts() {

        pw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pw.startSpinning();
        //String url=LiveUrl+"followingactivities?user_id="+userID;
        String url = LiveUrl+"user_post_data/?user_id=" + userID;
        System.out.println("URL IS" + url);
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                pw.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                pw.stopSpinning();
                                JSONObject suggested_jsonobj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                FeedItem movie = new FeedItem();
                                if (!suggested_jsonobj.optString("user_id").isEmpty())
                                {
                                    movie.setTitle(suggested_jsonobj.optString("username"));
                                    movie.setId(suggested_jsonobj.optString("user_id"));
                                    movie.setPostID(suggested_jsonobj.optString("id"));
                                    movie.setVideoID(suggested_jsonobj.optString("video_src"));
                                    movie.setImageThumb(suggested_jsonobj.optString("image_thumb"));
                                    movie.setVideoImage(suggested_jsonobj.optString("image_thumb"));
                                    movie.setThumbnail(suggested_jsonobj.optString("profile_image"));
                                    movie.setDate(suggested_jsonobj.optString("created"));
                                    movie.setVotecount(suggested_jsonobj.optString("votecount"));
                                    movie.setPost(suggested_jsonobj.optString("resize1"));
                                    movie.setPrivacyStatus(suggested_jsonobj.optString("privacy_status"));
                                    movie.setLikedStatus(suggested_jsonobj.optString("like_status"));
                                    movie.setLikedCount(suggested_jsonobj.optString("like_count"));
                                    movie.setLikeduserID(suggested_jsonobj.optString("like_user_id1"));
                                    movie.setLikedUserName(suggested_jsonobj.optString("like_username1"));
                                    movie.setCommentCount(suggested_jsonobj.optString("comment_count"));
                                    movie.setCaption(suggested_jsonobj.optString("caption"));
                                    movie.setCaptionUserName(suggested_jsonobj.optString("captionusername"));
                                    movie.setTagCount(suggested_jsonobj.optString("tag_count"));
                                    if (!suggested_jsonobj.optString("image_tag").matches("null")) {
                                        final JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(suggested_jsonobj.optString("image_tag"));
                                        final JSONObject jObj = arr.optJSONObject(0);
                                        movie.setx1Tag(jObj.optString("x1"));
                                        movie.sety1Tag(jObj.optString("y1"));
                                        movie.setx1userName(jObj.optString("name1"));
                                        movie.setx1userID(jObj.optString("user_id1"));
                                        movie.setx2Tag(jObj.optString("x2"));
                                        movie.sety2Tag(jObj.optString("y2"));
                                        movie.setx2userName(jObj.optString("name2"));
                                        movie.setx2userID(jObj.optString("user_id2"));
                                        movie.setx3Tag(jObj.optString("x3"));
                                        movie.sety3Tag(jObj.optString("y3"));
                                        movie.setx3userName(jObj.optString("name3"));
                                        movie.setx3userID(jObj.optString("user_id3"));
                                        movie.setx4Tag(jObj.optString("x4"));
                                        movie.sety4Tag(jObj.optString("y4"));
                                        movie.setx4userName(jObj.optString("name4"));
                                        movie.setx4userID(jObj.optString("user_id4"));

                                    }if (!suggested_jsonobj.optString("comment").isEmpty()) {
                                    final JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(suggested_jsonobj.optString("comment"));
                                    final JSONObject jObj = arr.optJSONObject(0);
                                    movie.setCommentID(jObj.optString("id"));
                                    movie.setCommentuserName(jObj.optString("username"));
                                    movie.setCommentProPic(jObj.optString("image"));
                                    movie.setCommentText(jObj.optString("comment"));
                                }
                                    feedsList.add(movie);
                                }
                                /*if(suggested_jsonobj.optString("id").isEmpty())
                                {
                                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }*/


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                pw.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                pw.stopSpinning();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    pw.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pw.stopSpinning();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sorry we couldn't complete your request.Please try again in a moment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());


            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
        movieReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    }
```

`

Comment: If you are saving your userID in SharedPreferences then why are you passing it in your newInstance ??

Comment: Like counts are refresh late what to do to refresh it immediately

Comment: I don't know if i really get your question, If you are referring to the movie.likeCount update, I guess the problem is that you call the method getProfilePosts just in the onCreateView, so the request is performed only when the onCreateView method is called that is just when you create the view for the fragment, try to call that method in another part of the code to see if the like count is correctly refreshed

Comment: where i have to call the getProfilePosts